# Question about unpaid presentations to organizations

Tags: conference, cv

I recently published a policy-based article in an academic journal that initially received some good attention from both practitioners and researchers.  Buoyed by the praise, I shared the publication with the Executive Directors of several nonprofit organizations that I admired in hopes that these organizations might find the arguments useful in their work (I am a both researcher and practitioner myself).

Much to my pleasant surprise, a few organizations wrote back and asked if I would have a Skype conversation with them (as well as forums of researchers with whom they have worked) to brief them on the publication and my findings.

Should I include these presentations on my CV to demonstrate my expertise on this particular policy issue?   If yes, how would I write this up and list this, especially since this is not a formal conference and the 'consult' with them is unpaid.

Thanks for the guidance in advance.

Comment: I doubt that you can put a conversation on your CV.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a conversation, I agree with Najib -- no, don't include.  If it's more like a seminar, then you could include it.  But there's another approach possible.  You might want to join a Board of Directors or Advisory Board of a relevant nonprofit.  Either as a regular member, or as a technical advisor.  That would definitely be appropriate to put in a CV.